# Confusion about printing elements with double-while

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, nested-loops

Here are two linked lists 'list1' and 'list2'.

Where list1 and list2 have two datas : data1, data2.

They have nodes below :  (data1, data2)

- `list1` : `(1,1) - (2,2)`
- `list2` : `(3,3) - (4,4) - (5,5)`

(bracket denotes each node)

```
while (list2 != NULL)
    {
        while (list1 != NULL)
        {
            printf("list1 contains : %d, %f\n", list1->data1, list1->data2);
            list1 = list1->NextNode;
        }

        printf("list2 contains : %d, %f\n", list2->data1, list2->data1);
        list2 = list2->NextNode;
    }
```

At First, I expected output as :

```
list1, list1, list2, list1, list1, list2, list1, list1, list2
```

(I mean a printing order)

But I got :

```
list1, list1, list2, list2, list2.
```

So my question is:

1. Why my expectation failed?
2. How should I change my code to make code works like my expectation?

Thanks

Comment: you don't reset `list1` back to the head of the list after the first time thru the outer loop so `list1 != NULL` fails on the 2nd iteration of the outer loop and thereafter.

Comment: @yano, Thanks for advice, Then How can I reset list1 end of the while-loop with out make list circular?

Comment: a linked list should have a `head` pointer that points to the first item in the list. This is always your starting point for any singly-linked list traversal. So you'll need to do something like `list1 = head; while(list1 != NULL){ ... }`. If `link1` _is_ your head pointer, save a temp copy of it before you start doing `list1 = list1->NextNode;` so you can restore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first execution of the inner while loop (its first and single iteration)

```
while (list2 != NULL)
    {
        while (list1 != NULL)
        {
            printf("list1 contains : %d, %f\n", list1->data1, list1->data2);
            list1 = list1->NextNode;
        }

        printf("list2 contains : %d, %f\n", list2->data1, list2->data1);
        list2 = list2->NextNode;
    }
```

the pointer `list1` becomes equal to `NULL`. Then after execution the code after the inner while loop the pointer `list2` is also equal to `NULL`. So the both while loops have only one iterations.

If you want to have the expected by you output like

```
list1, list1, list2, list1, list1, list2, list1, list1, list2
```

then write for example. Let's assume that the type of an object of the list is Node

```
    while (list2 != NULL)
    {
        for ( Node *temp1 = list1; temp1 != NULL; temp1 = temp1->NextNode )
        {
            printf("list1 contains : %d, %f\n", temp1->data1, temp1->data2);
        }

        printf("list2 contains : %d, %f\n", list2->data1, list2->data1);
        list2 = list2->NextNode;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any change that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Barmar There is an explanation of what happens in the program.